# laravel-chartjs not displaying anything

Tags: php, laravel, chart.js

I am using the package found [here](https://github.com/fxcosta/laravel-chartjs/blob/master/README.md) to use chartjs on my laravel project, I followed the instructions to install it and tried to load the example into a blade file. The issue is, nothing is displaying. Below I attached the example code, does anyone have experience using this package and could point me in the right direction?

The way I installed it, in this order was:

```
composer require fx3costa/laravelchartjs
added Fx3costa\LaravelChartJs\Providers\ChartjsServiceProvider::class to Providers
npm install chart.js --save
```

The example method.

```
private function createchart(){
        $chartjs = app()->chartjs
        ->name('lineChartTest')
        ->type('line')
        ->size(['width' => 400, 'height' => 200])
        ->labels(['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'])
        ->datasets([
            [
                "label" => "My First dataset",
                'backgroundColor' => "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.31)",
                'borderColor' => "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.7)",
                "pointBorderColor" => "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.7)",
                "pointBackgroundColor" => "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.7)",
                "pointHoverBackgroundColor" => "#fff",
                "pointHoverBorderColor" => "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                'data' => [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
            ],
            [
                "label" => "My Second dataset",
                'backgroundColor' => "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.31)",
                'borderColor' => "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.7)",
                "pointBorderColor" => "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.7)",
                "pointBackgroundColor" => "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.7)",
                "pointHoverBackgroundColor" => "#fff",
                "pointHoverBorderColor" => "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                'data' => [12, 33, 44, 44, 55, 23, 40],
            ]
        ])
        ->options([]);


        return $chartjs;
```

blade file:

```
<div style="width:75%;">
    {!! $chartjs->render() !!}
</div>
```

Comment: did you added chart js library to your blade file?

Comment: Isnt that what the npm command is doing?

Comment: no, it only install chart.js you also need to integrate it with your blade, for example with script tag

Comment: Got it, thank you, post as answer and ill accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that command `npm install chart.js --save` only installs chartjs libray (in /node_modules dir), you also need to integrate it with your project, for example with script tag placed in `<head>`:

```
<script src="path/to/chartjs/dist/Chart.js"></script>
```